Memory out of bound exception while trying to read .xlsx file using NPOI XSSFWorkbook
I am getting memory out bound exception while trying to read an excel file larger than 20 mb using XSSFWorkbook of NPOI in C#
Memory footprint is increasing by almost 2gbs for this 20 mb file
Since my application is of 32 bit architecture so i am have ram usage limitations and i have want full excel file in memory to perform operations faster
Is memory footprint for 20 mb .xlsx file is this high generally any suggestions or workaround to fix this?
I’ve tried ExcelDataReader library that reads the data with very less memory footprint but it doesn’t have writing capabilities.

How many cells are there? https://github.com/nissl-lab/npoi/issues/559#issuecomment-848447130

almost 170000 rows and 27 columns so 4590000 cells
